# Store multiple grep in one command output to a variable

Tags: bash, grep, variable

I am trying to get a list of IPs that are UP, so used `nmap` to first save all of them in a text file:

```
nmap -v -sn 10.10.10.1-254 -oG hosts.txt
```

Now I want to run another `nmap` command on these IPs, so to parse and get the IP from the text file.  I am trying the following, but its not working; the variable `v` does not have the value of IP saved:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do    
    v=$line|grep 'Up' -B1|grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}'

    echo $v
done < hosts.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script doesn't appear to be properly written:

```
v=$line | grep [...]
```

Assigning a variable has no output, so you are piping nothing into `grep`.

It would probably be simpler to point `awk` at your `hosts.txt` file:

```
$ nmap -v -sn 10.10.10.1/24 -oG hosts.txt > /dev/null 2>&1
$ awk '$NF=="Up" { print $2 }' hosts.txt
```

Given the format of the file created by `nmap` (forgive the different IP range; I'm clearly on a different network but the example is still valid):

```
$ head hosts.txt
# Nmap 7.60 scan initiated Fri May 11 10:14:28 2018 as: nmap -v -sn -oG hosts.txt 172.28.9.67/24
# Ports scanned: TCP(0;) UDP(0;) SCTP(0;) PROTOCOLS(0;)
Host: 172.28.9.0 (hostname1.internal)   Status: Up
Host: 172.28.9.1 (hostname2.internal)   Status: Up
```

If we're only interested in hosts which show `Status: Up`, helpfully the magic word is the last one on the line.  So we use `awk` to look only at those lines where the last field is equal to `Up`, and print the second field (to wit: the IP address).

Comment: Glad to have helped.  Welcome to U&L.  If this solved your problem to your satisfaction, please mark the answer as "accepted" so that others see you are no longer looking for an alternate solution.

Comment: Where can I mark it accepted?

Comment: To the left of the answer, there should be a grey checkmark.  Click it and it will become green.